# Typescript use List

Tags: c#, typescript, asp.net-core, aurelia

I'm using asp.net core with aurelia. I'm fetching forums from my asp.net core api like this:

```
forums = [];

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.fetchForums();
}

fetchForums() {
    this.http.fetch('forum/index')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.forums = data;
        });
}
```

Then in my html I show it like this:

```
<tr repeat.for="forum of forums">
  <td class="col-md-4">
    ${forum.name}
  </td>

  <td class="col-md-3">
    ${forum.description}
  </td>

  <td></td>

  <td>
    <i class="material-icons" click.trigger="destroy(forum)">&#xE872;</i>

    <a href="#">
      <i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

But the problem is that in my destroy method I need to get the id from the forum. But the id is undefined so now I cannot compile.

So how could I fix this? I cannot do something like this right:

```
List<Forum> forums = [];
```

instead of:

```
forums = [];
```

Comment: Within `TypeScript` you can use `Array` : `var forums : meType[] = new Array();`. This type has method "similar" to list `Array.push` which lets you add items to it.

Comment: @m.rogalski thanks for answering me. ```var forums : meType[] = new Array();``` should this be above the constructor? Because then I receive errors.

Comment: As @m.rogalski mentioned you can assign the type, in your example this is done where forums are declared as `forums: Array<Forum> = [];`

Comment: @Jamie I'm not experienced with `TypeScript`. Example that I've showed you is from my github project where I used it like `private  _indicees : number[];` and in constructor I have this :`this._indicees = new Array();` and I thought this might be something that you're looking for.

Comment: Something like this should mimic behavior of a list : `class Forum {}
class ForumsList {
    private _forums: Forum[];
    constructor() {
        this._forums = new Array<Forum>();
    }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define a type for a forum, I suggest using an interface:

```
declare interface IForum {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  messages: number;
  // etc....
}
```

You can declare the interface as above, which will make it global, or you could have it as an exported type of a module (in that case use `export` instead of `declare`)

Then in your class do this:

```
class Controller {
  public forums: IForum[] = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.fetchForums();
  }

  private fetchForums(): void {
    this.http.fetch('forum/index')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.forums = data;
      });
  }

  public destroy(forum: IForum): void {
    let id = forum.id;
    // do something with it...
  }
}
```